# Why does referencing a child include it when returning the parent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have forums, each forum has many posts, and each post has many comments. Posts belong to that forum, and comments belong to those posts.

I'm trying to return that forum with each of its posts, and each comment for each of those posts. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
public function showposts($id)
{
    $forum = Forum::find($id);

    $comments = $forum->posts->each(function($post)
    {
        $comment = $post->comments;
    });

    return response()->json($forum, 201);
}
```

What I don't understand is why this works.

If I don't include the $comments section then it will just return the forum without any posts or comments, and if I remove the loop then only the forum and posts will be returned without comments.

I'm still only returning the forum though, $comments is not included at all, and yet it affects it. Can anyone please explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because calling `$forum->posts` will lazy load the forums related posts. And calling the `$post->comments` on each of them will lazy load the posts related comments.

A more elegant and performant way would be to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationships:

```
public function showposts($id)
{
    $forum = Forum::with('posts.comments')->find($id);

    return response()->json($forum, 201);
}
```